# Quotient group in finite abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Statement  "If G is finite abelian group  and H is its subgroup  then there is a normal subgroup N of G such that   G/N is isomorphic  to H ."

Clearly  [G:H] divides order of G   .As G is abelian therefor there exists  a normal subgroup of order  [G: H] ( Say N).
Now  o (G)/o (H)=o (N) .
I.e o (G)/o (N) =o (H)  but How can I prove above statement?

Comment: Have you seen the structure theorem for finite abelian groups?

Comment: This is not a trivial result. One way to prove it is to first prove that the character group of $G$ is isomorphic to $G$.